# vb.net - Remove border around Progress-bar

Tags: vb.net, progress-bar, border

How would i go about removing the thin border around the edges of the Progress-bar tool? There doesn't seem to be any properties to change the style. It looks like the default 3d border.

Comment: Are you talking about the Visual Styles progress bar, or the classic Windows 2000-ish progress bar?

Comment: Either way you'd probably have to write your own control for that.

Comment: Visual styles progress bar.

Comment: I'm looking into that now, but was hoping there was a nice way to simply prevent the border from being drawn along with everything else.

Comment: Well if it's Visual Styles then it is most certainly impossible, as there is some hard C/C++/machine code behind it.

Comment: Damn.. Thanks. I'll look into some alternatives.

Comment: You're welcome. The simplest thing that comes to my mind is if you'd make a picture version of it with the border edited out, and then made it into a custom control. It's not a very good workaround, but it is a workaround. :p

Comment: Simple, ***create your own***.

Comment: Have a reference for that simple claim?

Comment: @user2366092 You can find the source-code of a lot of personalized ProgressBar user-controls just Googling it, no excuses!. In CodeProject site for example you can find some ProgressBars very professionals.

Comment: @user2366092 `Have a reference for that simple claim?` Sure do, ***it's called study, research, learn, fail (retry) and Google.***

Comment: A lot of work for a custom border if you otherwise want it to look and act the same

Answer (score 4):

It is not the best solution from a programmatically correct point of view, but it works and is an easy solution.

- You create a `Panel` control
- You put the `BorderStyle` property of the `Panel` to `None`
- You moove your `Progress Bar` inside the `Panel` control
- You rezise the `Panel` and the `Progress Bar` so that dimension of the `Progress Bar` is a few pixels larger than the dimension of the `Panel` control.  This way, when the controls are drawn, the borders of the `Progress Bar` do not show because they are outside of `Panel` control
- You set the `Anchors` property of the `Progress Bar` to `Left`, `Right`, `Top` and `Bottom` so that when you rezise the `Panel` control, the `Progress Bar` inside resizes well.
- You resize and place your `Panel` where you need it (and the `Progress Bar` will resize well into it)

And your done.  As I said, it is not a nice solution from a programmation point of view, but overall it works well and allow you to do what you want without spending too much time.